# slove error empty pictures datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
        Dim bytes As Byte() = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(27).Value
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
            Form4.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                
        End Using
        Form4.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Gave me this error message:
[image]

Following a comment suggesting to check the value of the cell, I tried this:

```
        Dim bytes As Byte() = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(27).Value
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
            Form4.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

            If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(27).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                MessageBox.Show("empty ")
            End If                
        End Using
        Form4.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

but I still got the same error message.

Comment: You need to check if the cell has a database null value: `If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(27).Value Is DbNull.Value Then` and decide what to do in that case.

Comment: Dim bytes As Byte() = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(27).Value
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
            Form4.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

            If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(27).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                MessageBox.Show("empty ")
            End If
        End Using
        Form4.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: 1. You need to do the check *before* trying to use it as if it were an array of bytes. 2. Please make sure to use [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) and set it as the default for new projects.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Instead, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there is a value in the cell before using it, something like:

```
If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(27).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
    MessageBox.Show("empty ")

Else
    Dim bytes As Byte() = DirectCast(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(27).Value, Byte())
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        Form4.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    End If                

End Using

Form4.ShowDialog()
```